# git+svn osx mavericks: fatal: Cannot open '.git/Git_exc7sv': Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: xcode, osx-mavericks, git-svn

I recently updated from Mountain Lion to Mavericks and for some reason I can't use any git+svn commands anymore, it doesn't matter which repo I use, I all get simular errors:

```
xxx@xxx:/path/$ sudo git svn clone http://svn.domain/path/ .

Initialized empty Git repository in /path/.git/
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: '/xxx' path not found
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
fatal: Cannot open '.git/Git_exc7sv': Resource temporarily unavailable
hash-object -w --stdin-paths --no-filters: command returned error: 128

error closing pipe: Bad file descriptor at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 0.
error closing pipe: Bad file descriptor at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 0.
```

I have updated Xcode to the most recent version and installed the command line tools, rebooting the system has no effect.

Comment: [This post](http://sb-code.blogspot.com/2013/03/git-fetch.html) says that the problem is that `/path/` is on a NAS, and worked on another drive. If you're sharing over NFS, I suspect it's a permissions issue.